# What does it mean that the Higgs has a nonzero vacuum expectation value?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, higgs

What does it mean that the Higgs has a nonzero vacuum expectation value? Are there any other important field with nonzero VEV? How is this related to the 100-orders magnitude wrong prediction?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96381/higgs-field-the-vacuum-expectation-value?rq=1

Comment: That there is a probability for a particle to "emerge" out of the vaccuum?

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43714/what-is-the-role-of-the-vacuum-expectation-value-in-symmetry-breaking-and-the-ge?rq=1